# Should the "Glitch" and "Bug" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't think there's an obvious, meaningful difference between these two terms.  The questions in each tag seem pretty similar.

Comment: I don't know... I think a bug is a bug that sucks, while a glitch is a minor bug that causes a minor amusement but does not break the gameplay

Comment: @Tobias I suspect many of us feel these words imply slightly different things, but I also suspect that everyone's definition is a little bit different.  Unless these words clearly define different things *to the community as a whole*, there is little value in separate tags.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the tags it relates to have all since been removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for the record:

- [`glitch`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glitch) x7
- [`bug`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) x16
- [`bugs`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) (Synonym for bug)

I'm totally in favor of merging it all into `bug` and setting up [synonyms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/synonyms) (thanks Grace).

Comment: I'm good for creating a synonym and for merging. I don't think there's a serious necessity to distinguish these. From a practicality standpoint, they are all used on basically the same topic. So this conclusion keeps in line with how we are actually using the tags.

Comment: In case all the upvoters haven't noticed, Arda Xi [setup a synonym for y'all to vote on!](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/synonyms) ♪

Comment: Neat, I didn't realize synonyms were a vote-able thing.

Comment: As the synonym has passed, I have gone and performed the merge. I did review the list, and the only questionable entity was [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-do-you-play-with-master-hand-in-super-smash-brothers-melee), as bug tends to have more negative connotations, but I think it's fine.

Comment: I had no idea gamers used "bug" more often than "glitch". I've always thought gamers used "glitch" more. In fact, there's "glitching" which refers specifically to exploiting glitches (for whatever motive), but not a similar term for exploiting bugs. Could be just me, though...

Comment: @The Annoying might be carryover from the programmer/gamer crowd around here.

Comment: @C. Ross: Ah, now that you mention it :)